# Is SF&F.SE the appropriate place to ask about Comic Cover Variations and Quality Approximation?

Tags: discussion, comics

I know this is a very broad topic. If SF&F.SE is the correct forum for this type of question I plan to ask much more specific questions related to the subject.

Comment: Could you maybe edit in a few example questions?  I'm not sure what you mean by 'quality approximation'.

Comment: I really wanted to know about investing in comics. Which variations are/aren't worth anything or are more rare or common, etc. Quality approximation was in reference to Determining the quality of a comic book. I know the terminology (found at a different site); but, I am assuming that "light fingerprints noted in right mid quadrant" is much less frowned upon than "2 inch rip in front cover."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Comics proposal up on Area 51. But until it goes Beta, it wouldn't be available for such questions.

If I understand your question correctly, this isn't an appropriate place. While I would personally welcome all comics questions that pertain to the science fiction elements of comic books (or even the story elements of comic books with a science fiction storyline) and urge others to do so as well...

Questions that pertain only to the "comic-bookishness" of comic books seem inappropriate. If you're asking about how many promotional cover variations they made for the new Octopusman series, it's just not really on-topic (even though a question about one of those images *might* be on topic).

Comment: While this is the right answer, it appears the admins have closed the Comics proposal as noted as a duplicate of the SF&F site.

Comment: This one though: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47733/comics-sequential-art ?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you could come to this for a site right now would be the [Graphic Design site](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/), depending on exactly what your question is. Things like the quality of the paper, images, etc would definitely be on topic there, but I'm not 100% your questions would fit. You might still take a look there, however.